# Problema con manejo de evento javascript al perder foco de un elemento <span> HTML

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo este código:

```
<span contenteditable="true" id="Texto_publicacion_user_main_click" name="hola" onclick="publicar_usuario_texto();">Publica algo aquí</span>
             <span contenteditable="true" id="Texto_publicacion_user_main" name="hola"></span>

function publicar_usuario_texto() {
    document.getElementById("Texto_publicacion_user_main_click").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("Texto_publicacion_user_main").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("Texto_publicacion_user_main").focus();

}
```

Necesito que cuando el usuario deje de seleccionar el elemento se chequee el elemento y si esta vacío que aparezca otro texto pero si por el contrario no está vacío que no pase nada (mantenga el texto que el usuario ingresó)

Answer (score 1):

Te pongo una solucion basada en css, sin javascript

```css
span {
  width:30%;
  display: inline-block;
  background:#EEEEEE;
}
span:empty:before{
content:"publica algo"
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true" name="hola">Publica algo aquí</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando sólo **JavaScript** podrías deberías agregar un `EventListener` de `focusout` para allí chequear si el `input` está vacío y agregar el texto deseado

**Por ejemplo;**

```js
    var ejemplo = document.getElementById("ejemplo")
    ejemplo.addEventListener("focusout", funcionEjemplo);
 
    function funcionEjemplo(){

        if(ejemplo.value.length == 0)
        
        {

        ejemplo.value = "Valor!";
        
        }

    }
```

```html
 <h5>Utilizando JavaSript</h5>
  <input type="text" id="ejemplo">
```

En caso de hacerlo con **jQuery** podrías hacer lo siguiente;

```js
      $('#ejemplo').on('focusout',function(){

        if($(this).val().length == 0)
        {
          $(this).val("Valor!");
        }

      });
```

```html
  <h5>Utilizando jQuery</h5>
  <input type="text" id="ejemplo">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Sin embargo, con la poca información que dejas, asumo, que te podría ser útil la propiedad `placeholder` de un `input`, por ejemplo;

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Valor!">
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Como bien dice @JuanSalvadorPortugal en su respuesta podrías solucionar el inconveniente con la propiedad ***placeholder*** de HTML si cambias tu elemento `<span>` por un elemento `<input>`, sin embargo, imagino que estás intentando emular el comportamiento de esta propiedad directamente en tu elemento `<span>` mediante javascript.

Podrías utilizar el evento `blur` (el cual justamente se activa cuando se pierde el foco del elemento en cuestión) mediante un **listener** que garantice un chequeo continuo del elemento, entonces al dispararse el evento chequeas si está vacio el elemento (en tu caso un `<span>`).

> También sería bueno que mejores un poco el css de los elementos
>    ya que si vas a estar cambiando el texto que tiene internamente sería bueno que el usuario pudiera notarlo, ya que cuando
>   un `<span>` queda vacio el ancho "se reduce" a 0 y para un usuario
>   común no sería posible notar que está sucediendo a ciencia cierta. De
>   todas formas le incluí css a tus `<span>` en mi solución para que
>   aprecies los cambios al realizar el onclick y el onblur.

A continuación dejo el código con lo que he comentado anteriormente:

```js
var span= document.getElementById("Texto_publicacion_user_main_click");

function publicar_usuario_texto() {
 
span.innerHTML ="";
   
}

span.onblur = function(){

if(span.innerHTML==""){
span.innerHTML ="Otro texto";

}

};
```

```css
span {
  width:30%;
  display: inline-block;
  background:#EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<span contenteditable="true" id="Texto_publicacion_user_main_click" name="hola" onclick="publicar_usuario_texto();">Publica algo aquí</span>
```

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo